# Write method with trailing return type to change based on method call?

Tags: c++, struct, types, return, trailing

I have a class titled `Eclipse` with a private struct member containing ~30 fields of various data types.

I have a method that will return a data field from the struct, based on a field number passed in as a parameter.

Seeing as the struct contains data of various types, I opted to use the `auto` keyword with a trailing return type based on a templated parameter. My method header is below.

```
template<typename TheType>
auto getColumnData(TheType toGet, int fieldNum) -> decltype(toGet) {
    // switch statement to return fields based on fieldNum
}
```

If I want to return a column that is an `int`, I call `getColumnData(0, 1);`. The first parameter is only used to determine the return type of the method, and the second parameter determines the field number to return to the method caller.

Theoretically, this would cause the return type of `getColumnData()` to be `int` and return the first column (corresponding to the first field) of the struct. But I'm receiving this compilation error:

> no viable conversion from returned value of type 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to function return type 'decltype(toGet)' (aka 'int')`

I understand that if I were to call this method with an `int` as the first parameter, and a field number that corresponds to a field returning a `std::string`, there would be issues. But, based on checks in other classes, this case would never occur.

Is there any way that I can force my compiler to accept this code, even if it might not be correct for certain cases?

I know that I could just overload the method, but I'd rather not have multiple different methods for basically the same purpose if I can figure out how to accomplish the task in only one.

Also, if my understanding of any of this information seems incorrect, please let me know. I'm very new to C++, so I'm just learning these features as I go.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. If the first parameter is an `int`, the `decltype` specifies that the function returns an `int`, by definition. Full stop. End of story. Everything else you wrote from that point on is irrelevant. The instantiated template function must return an `int`, no ifs, ands, or buts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a method's return type dynamically at runtime like you are attempting to do.  Your first parameter is not a data type known at compile-time.  It is just an integer that is populated at runtime, so you can't make compile-time decisions based on it at all.

A simple solution would be to use [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17 or later) or [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/variant.html) (C++11 and later) as the return type:

```
using FieldType = std:::variant<int, std::string>;

FieldType getColumnData(int fieldNum) {
    // switch statement to return fields based on fieldNum
}
```

```
int i = std::get<int>(getColumnData(1));
std::string s = std::get<std::string>(getColumnData(2));
```

Otherwise, you would have to make the return type be a template parameter, not a method parameter:

```
template<typename TheType>
TheType getColumnData(int fieldNum) {
    // switch statement to return fields based on fieldNum
}
```

But then you run into the problem that not all fields will be convertible to the return type (can't return a `std::string` field when an `int` is requested, etc), so you can't just `switch` on the `fieldNum` since it is not evaluated at compile-time.

You might be tempted to make the field number be a template parameter so it is constant at compile-time, and then specialize on it:

```
template<const int FieldNum>
auto getColumnData() { return 0; };

template<> int getColumnData<1>() { return private_struct.Field1; }
template<> std::string getColumnData<2>() { return private_struct.Field2; }
// etc...
```

```
int i = getColumnData<1>();
std::string s = getColumnData<2>();
```

But I get errors when I try to do that on a templated class method ("explicit specialization in non-namespace scope").

You might be tempted to do something like this, and hope the compiler optimizes away the unused branches:

```
template<const int FieldNum>
auto getColumnData() {
    if (FieldNum == 1) return private_struct.Field1;
    if (FieldNum == 2) return private_struct.Field2;
    //etc...
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
template<const int FieldNum>
auto getColumnData()
{
    switch (FieldNum) {
        case 1: return private_struct.Field1;
        case 2: return private_struct.Field2;
        // etc...
    }
    return 0;
};
```

```
int i = getColumnData<1>();
std::string s = getColumnData<2>();
```

But that doesn't work, either ("inconsistent deduction for auto return type" errors).